# Remove property from Property pane in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**Is it possible to remove a form property or set of properties from the Properties pane in Visual Studio?**

Backstory: I've made some UserControls which inherit the common form properties, but I want to remove the "Anchor" and "Dock" properties from the Properties pane in Visual Studio, since the UserControl will be using different resizing logic, logic that anchoring and docking don't seem to support.

I'm thinking it's an annotation of some kind, but I'm not entirely sure, and I wasn't able to find anything on Google.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute you want is Browsable
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.browsable.aspx
override Dock and Anchor on those user controls, add that attribute (with a "false" value) to them and see if that works (make sure you recompile in order for the designer to load the changes)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the Browsable attribute to the property:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[Browsable(false)]
public override AnchorStyles Anchor {
  get {
    return base.Anchor;
  }
  set {
    base.Anchor = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to override your properties, you can make your control implement the ICustomTypeDescriptor in order to control what is shown in the property grid. To do this you can implement every method apart for the one returning the properties delegating its implementation to the standard implementation (static methods of TypeDescriptor). The implementation of these methods should be as follows:

```
public String GetClassName()
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this,true);
}

public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this,true);
}

public String GetComponentName()
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
}

public TypeConverter GetConverter()
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
}

public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent() 
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
}

public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty() 
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
}

public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType) 
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
}

public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes) 
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
}

public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
}

public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd) 
{
    return this;
}
```

The method that has to be implemented is GetProperties. It returns a PropertyDescriptionCollection that in your case should contain every PropertyDescriptor apart the ones that you want to hide. Something like this:

```
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties() 
{
    pdColl = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
        if (pd.Name != "Dock" && pd.Name != "Anchor")
            pdColl.Add(pd);
    return pdColl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the property and set the `Browsable` attribute to false.

```
[Browsable(false)]
public override AnchorStyles Anchor
{
    get
    {
        return AnchorStyles.None;
    }
    set
    {
       // maybe throw a not implemented/ don't use message?
    }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public override DockStyle Dock
{
    get
    {
        return DockStyle.None;
    }
    set
    {

    }
}
```